# Formula to change output of an index match formula based on the cell adjacent to the indexed one?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm taking raw data from one spreadsheet and moving it into another sheet for a report. The raw data kind of looks like this:

| site | parameter | value | qualifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | chlorine | 14 mg/L | U |
| b | chlorine | 19 mg/L | J |
| a | pH | 6.8 |  |
| b | pH | 7.1 |  |

And the table I'm making currently looks like this:

| parameter | site a | site b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chlorine(mg/L) | 14 | 19 |
| pH | 6.8 | 7.1 |

I used the following function to do this:

> =INDEX(data!$C$2:$C$100,MATCH(1,(B$1=data!$A$2:$A$100)*($A2=data!$B$2:$B$100),0))

So I'm searching through the raw data to find where the parameter and the site are specific values, and it yields the value where both are true.

My issue is that now I want to go through again and find every value where the qualifier in the original data is U (this means nondetect so the value given is essentially a guess), and change it so that that cell is blank in the final table. So I want my final table to look like this, because in my example raw data, site a's chlorine value had a U qualifier:

| parameter | site a | site b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chlorine(mg/L) | -- | 19 |
| pH | 6.8 | 7.1 |

The only way I can think to do it right now would have me repeating the formula I already have a bunch of times in a really big nested function using IFs and XLOOKUP. I want to avoid this if possible because that makes it much harder to notice errors. I'm wondering if I can somehow use the "OR" function for this, but I don't know how to call adjacent cells in excel syntax, if that's possible. I don't want to actually return what's in the qualifier column, so I can't use OFFSET, either.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work for you using <kbd>XLOOKUP()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(
    1,
    (
        TEXTBEFORE(
            $F2,
            "(",
            ,
            ,
            ,
            $F2
        ) = $B$2:$B$5
    ) *
        (
            TEXTAFTER(
                G$1,
                " "
            ) = $A$2:$A$5
        ) * ($D$2:$D$5 <> "U"),
    $C$2:$C$5,
    "--"
)
```

---

Formula needs to fill down and fill right!

---

If you want to return an array then you could try this:

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(F2:F3),COLUMNS(G1:H1),LAMBDA(α,φ,
 XLOOKUP(1,(TEXTBEFORE(INDEX(F2:F3,α),"(",,,,INDEX(F2:F3,α))=B2:B5)*
 (TEXTAFTER(INDEX(G1:H1,φ)," ")=A2:A5)*(D2:D5<>"U"),C2:C5,"--")))
```

---

Comment: I think that would definitely work, but my actual dataset is really large and I was hoping to avoid having to make more than one table. I ended up using this formula: =if(INDEX(data!$D$2:$D$100,MATCH(1,(B$1=data!$A$2:$A$100)*($A2=data!$B$2:$B$100),0))="U","--",INDEX(data!$C$2:$C$100,MATCH(1,(B$1=data!$A$2:$A$100)*($A2=data!$B$2:$B$100),0)). It's a little more complicated than I would like but not nearly as bad as I thought it would be. So the original function now returns the qualifier column and the if function switches it back to the value column if its not a U value. Thank you though!

Comment: Many ways to reach `Rome` not sure how your initial formula will work since you have the parameter in the `Table1` as `chlorine` while in `Table2` it is `chlorine(mg/L)` so there is no formula to parse those delimiters. Weird. Need to investigate more!

Answer (score 0):

Tidying up your labels (I think they must be tidier than in the tables you posted since your working formula isn't doing any "parsing", e.g. for *mg/L*) you could use a single `FILTER()` function:
[image: screenshot illustrating FILTER() solution]

The formula in C9 (copied down and across) is

```
=FILTER($C$2:$C$5,($B$2:$B$5=$B9)*($A$2:$A$5=C$8)*($D$2:$D$5<>"U"),"--")
```

Comment: Yes, my actual table looks different. i typed this one out quickly rather than copy-pasting some of the actual data because I'm paranoid about sharing data from work. Thank you for the idea to use filter, the concept of using * to use multiple parameters is new to me, so I'm still pretty ignorant about which functions can use them. Thanks!